# Codeigniter 3.1.9 : Session Lost when using redirect

Tags: codeigniter-3

I faced one issue when upgraded codeigniter 2.2.0 into 3.1.9

Ex : I'm set a session in page1 and then redirecting into page2. After redirect, Unable to get page1 session into page2. In page2, I printed the session is showing empty.

Page1:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('user', $data );
```

Page2:

```
$user = $this->session->userdata('user');
```

I'm not facing this issue in codeigniter 2. Only facing in Codeigniter3.

Comment: please add some code you have tried

Answer (score 0):

Your code is OK.

Before using session library in codeigniter you need to configure session driver and load the session library, make sure you have correct setup.

To configure session driver goto `/application/config/config.php`, if you are using files for session driver make sure you have read and write permission for `$config['sess_save_path']` location.

You can autoload the session library by adding `session` to `$autoload['libraries']` array in `/application/config/autoload.php`

Comment: Yeah, I already set a session drivers as a files and set a all permissions for given directory inside the 'sess_save_path' and then autoload also set as fine. But No luck

Comment: change codeigniter environment to `development` and check if there is warnings\errors

Comment: In server cookies set as "PHPSESSID", But In our codeigniter set in "ci_session". So this session issue occurred. Do you have any idea about this?